# How to formally prove the chain rule for multivariable vector-valued functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:G\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow$$G'\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable at $x_0\in{G}$ and $g:G'\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}^p$ be differentiable at $f(x_0)=y_0\in{G'}$. Claim: $g(f(x_0))$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $D(g$$\circ$f)($x_0$)$=$$Dg(y_0)$$\circ$$Df(y_0)$.

What I have done:

Since $f$ is differentiable, $(g\circ{f})$$(x_0+u)=g(f(x_0+u))=g(f(x_0)+Df(x_0)u+||u||\epsilon_1(u))$, where $\epsilon_1(u)$ tends to zero as $u$ approaches zero. Next let's denote $Df(x_0)u+||u||\epsilon_1(u)=h(u)$. Then we get

$g(f(x_0+u))$

$=g(y_0+h(u))$

$=g(y_0+Df(x_0)u+||u||\epsilon(u)$)

Further, since $g$ is differentiable, $g(y_0+h(u))$=$g(y_0)+Dg(y_0)h(u)+||h(u)||\epsilon_2(h(u)))$, where $\epsilon_2(h(u))$ should tend to zero as $h(u)$ approaches zero.

Thus,

$(g\circ{f})$$(x_0+u)=g(y_0)+f(x_0)+Dg(y_0)(Df(x_0)u+||u||\epsilon_1(u))+||Df(x_0)u+||u||\epsilon_1(u)||\epsilon_2(Df(x_0)u+||u||\epsilon_1(u)))$

I need a little help to wrap this up.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Modulo details, this is the argument you're aiming for:
\begin{align*}
y_{0} + k &= f(x_{0} + h) = f(x_{0}) + \underbrace{Df(x_{0})\, h + o(\|h\|)}_{k}; \\
(g \circ f)(x_{0} + h)
  &= g(y_{0} + k) \\
  &= g(y_{0}) + Dg(y_{0})\, k + o(\|k\|) \\
  &= g(y_{0}) + Dg(y_{0})\, Df(x_{0})\, h + o(\|h\|).
\end{align*}
The chain rule follows at once from the characterization of the derivative as the "linear coefficient" in a linear approximation.

The main technical point to address is: If $k = f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})$, why can $o(\|k\|)$ be replaced by $o(\|h\|)$?

Comment: Is it because both tend to zero as $h\rightarrow{0}$?

Comment: Essentially "yes", though you need the fact that matrix multiplication is continuous, i.e., that for a fixed matrix/linear transformation $Df(x_{0})$, there exists a real number $M$ such that $\|Df(x_{0})\, h\| \leq M\, \|h\|$. Not sure how careful you're expected to be with analytic details, or what you're free to assume about matrix products, however.

Comment: Just had a closer read of your initial post; note that differentiability of $f$ at $x_{0}$ means$$f(x_{0} + u) = f(x_{0}) + Df(x_{0})u + \epsilon(u),\qquad \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\|\epsilon(u)\|}{\|u\|} = 0.$$This differs from what you have; does that help?

Comment: I am afraid, no. Is it about ordering the terms appropriately or some manipulations?

Comment: The ordering is what comes from direct substitution: In the notation of my answer (but using $\epsilon_{1}$ for the "error" in $f$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ for the error in $g$),\begin{align*}g(y_{0} + k) &= g(y_{0}) + Dg(y_{0}) k + \epsilon_{2}(k) \\ &= g(y_{0}) + Dg(y_{0}) Df(x_{0})h + \bigl[Dg(y_{0}) \epsilon_{1}(h) + \epsilon_{2}(k)\bigr].\end{align*}The point is to show the norm of the square bracket terms divided by $\|h\|$ goes to $0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Many thanks! The only problem now is to show that $\frac{||h(u)||}{||u||}$ is bounded.

Comment: Andrew D. Hwang, could you please take a look at my other problem on multivariate calculus involving dirrerentiability there ----> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963814/proving-a-condition-on-differentiable-multivariable-function