# Proving a condition on differentiable multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f$: $G\subset\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)\in{G}$ and $$ \lim_{(x, y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{f(x,y) -a -b(x-x_0) -c(y-y_0)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^{2} + (y-y_0)^{2}}} = 0.$$ The task is to prove that then $a=f(x_0,y_0),b=f_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $c=f_y(x_0,y_0)$.

Since $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$, there exists a linear function $L$ such that

$$\lim_{(h_1, h_2) \to (0, 0)} \frac{f(x_0 + h_1, y_0 + h_2) - f(x_0, y_0) - L(h_1, 
h_2)}{\sqrt{h_1^{2} + h_2^{2}}} = 0,$$where

$$
L(h_1, h_2) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)\, h_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)\, h_2.
$$Now we can substitute $L(h_1,h_2)$ in and get

$$\lim_{(h_1, h_2) \to (0, 0)} \frac{f(x_0 + h_1, y_0 + h_2) - f(x_0, y_0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)\, h_1 - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)h_2}{\sqrt{h_1^{2} + h_2^{2}}} = 0,$$ 
which is equivalent to $$ \lim_{(x, y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{f(x,y) -f(x_0,y_0) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)(x-x_0) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)(y-y_0)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^{2} + (y-y_0)^{2}}} = 0,$$because $(x-x_0)\rightarrow{0}$ and $(y-y_0)\rightarrow{0}$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)$.

Therefore it must (?) hold that $f(x,y) -a -b(x-x_0) -c(y-y_0)=f(x,y) -f(x_0,y_0) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)(x-x_0) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)(y-y_0)$

which implies (?) that $a=f(x_0,y_0),b=f_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $c=f_y(x_0,y_0)$. I am thinking that maybe my proof is wrong and based too much on intuition rather than formal mathematical reasoning. I am asking for comments and tips on how to possibly modify or redone it if it's not correct. There may be other approaches to this problem as well. I will appreciate your answers.